# PHP, is it possible to Convert a generated text file to a rich text file?

Tags: php

I have a script that takes the articles  out of the database and places them in a .txt file, but i would like to place them in a .rtf format, is there a way to convert or compile a .rtf file?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTF is just a text format (kind of like html), so yes, you can convert it easily enough by opening the file, inserting the right rtf codes (basically, just a header), and saving it as a .rtf file.  Google for the rtf spec.  What would get complicated is things like making headlines bold, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a lot of information on this on Google.

http://lab.artlung.com/rtf/

Seems to possibly be what you are looking for. I found that link through [this forum thread](http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/writing-a-rtf-document-using-php-15317.html).